# Dependent dropdown does not work in proper way when using with model in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

when i am selected the floor particular hall list and particular floor image should be loaded into the system.

this is the floormodel

```
class FloorModel {
  final int id;
  final String floorname;
  final String floorimg;
  final String floorshortname;

  FloorModel(this.id, this.floorname, this.floorimg, this.floorshortname);
}
```

this is the hallmodel

```
class HallModel {
  final int id;
  final String hallname;
  final String hallpoint;
  final String hallshortname;

  HallModel(this.id, this.hallname, this.hallpoint, this.hallshortname);
}
```

this is how the system should works [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H11lu.png)

and this is my implementation and it does not work in proper way.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../models/FloorModel.dart';
import '../../models/HallModel.dart';

class FOCMap extends StatefulWidget {
  const FOCMap({super.key});

  @override
  State<FOCMap> createState() => _FOCMapState();
}
List<FloorModel> floorlist = [
  FloorModel(1, 'Ground Floor', 'img/groundfloor.jpg', 'ground'),
  FloorModel(2, '1st floor', 'img/first.jpeg', 'first'),
  FloorModel(3, '2nd Floor', 'img/second.jpeg', 'second'),
  FloorModel(4, 'B1 Floor', 'img/b1.jpeg', 'BOne'),
  FloorModel(5, 'B2 Floor', 'img/b2.jpeg', 'BTwo'),
  FloorModel(6, 'B3 Floor', 'img/b3.jpeg', 'BThree'),
];

List<HallModel> halllist = [
  HallModel(1, '001', 'img/groundfloor.jpg', 'ground'),
  HallModel(2, '002', 'img/first.jpeg', 'first'),
  HallModel(3, '003', 'img/second.jpeg', 'second'),
  HallModel(4, '101', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BOne'),
  HallModel(5, 'Admin', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BTwo'),
  HallModel(6, 'office', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BThree'),
];

FloorModel _selectedfloorModel = floorlist.first;
HallModel _selectedhallModel = halllist.first;


class _FOCMapState extends State<FOCMap> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Faculty of Computing"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(_selectedfloorModel.floorimg),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            )
        ),
        children: [
          DropdownButton<String?>(
              value: _selectedfloorModel,
              items: dataset.keys.map((e) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String?>(
                  value: e,
                  child: Text('$e'),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: onCarModelChanged),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          DropdownButton<String?>(
              value: selectedMake,
              items: (dataset[_selectedfloorModel] ?? []).map((e) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String?>(
                  value: e,
                  child: Text('$e'),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedMake = val!;
                });
              }),
          //
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

when the particular floor shortname is equals to hall shortname particular hall list and particular floor image should be load into the system.

im stucking this question within more days could anyone please help me to resolve this problem
thank you,
chamithu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you,

```
 class FloorModel {
  final int id;
  final String floorname;
  final String floorimg;
  final String floorshortname;

  FloorModel(this.id, this.floorname, this.floorimg, this.floorshortname);
}

class HallModel {
  final int id;
  final String hallname;
  final String hallpoint;
  final String hallshortname;

  HallModel(this.id, this.hallname, this.hallpoint, this.hallshortname);
}


class FOCMap extends StatefulWidget {
  const FOCMap({super.key});

  @override
  State<FOCMap> createState() => _FOCMapState();
}
List<FloorModel> floorlist = [
  FloorModel(1, 'Ground Floor', 'img/groundfloor.jpg', 'ground'),
  FloorModel(2, '1st floor', 'img/first.jpeg', 'first'),
  FloorModel(3, '2nd Floor', 'img/second.jpeg', 'second'),
  FloorModel(4, 'B1 Floor', 'img/b1.jpeg', 'BOne'),
  FloorModel(5, 'B2 Floor', 'img/b2.jpeg', 'BTwo'),
  FloorModel(6, 'B3 Floor', 'img/b3.jpeg', 'BThree'),
];

List<HallModel> halllist = [
  HallModel(1, '001', 'img/groundfloor.jpg', 'ground'),
  HallModel(2, '002', 'img/first.jpeg', 'first'),
  HallModel(3, '003', 'img/second.jpeg', 'second'),
  HallModel(4, '101', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BOne'),
  HallModel(5, 'Admin', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BTwo'),
  HallModel(6, 'office', 'img/second.jpeg', 'BThree'),
];

FloorModel _selectedfloorModel = floorlist.first;
HallModel _selectedhallModel = halllist.first;

String select_img = '';


class _FOCMapState extends State<FOCMap> {
  
  check(){
    halllist.forEach ((e){
     
      if(e.hallshortname == _selectedfloorModel.floorshortname){
         print(e.hallpoint); // for halllist image
        setState((){
          select_img = e.hallpoint;
        });
      }
    });
  }
  
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Faculty of Computing"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(_selectedfloorModel.floorimg),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            )
        ),
        child: Column(
        children: [
          DropdownButton<FloorModel>(
              value: _selectedfloorModel,
              items: floorlist.map((item) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<FloorModel>(
                  child: Text(item.floorname),
                  value: item,
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (value){
               setState((){
                  _selectedfloorModel = value!;
               });
                
                check();
              }
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
           DropdownButton<HallModel>(
              value: _selectedhallModel,
              items: halllist.map((item) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<HallModel>(
                  child: Text(item.hallname),
                  value: item,
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (value){
               setState((){
                  _selectedhallModel = value!;
               });
              }
          ),
          Text(select_img)
//           DropdownButton<HallModel>(
//               value: selectedMake,
//               items: (dataset[_selectedfloorModel] ?? []).map((e) {
//                 return DropdownMenuItem<String?>(
//                   value: e,
//                   child: Text('$e'),
//                 );
//               }).toList(),
//               onChanged: (val) {
//                 setState(() {
//                   selectedMake = val!;
//                 });
//               }),
          
        ],
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: brother all working proper way but when i selected any floor same hall list will loaded.i want to specific hall list for specific floor .i think it can be done using hall short name.